# knockout observable depending on a 'sibling' of the same object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

this code will work:

```
var a = {};
a.b = ko.observable(1);
a.c = ko.computed(function(){ return a.b() + 1; });
```

this one will not (obviously):

```
var a = {
    b : ko.observable(1),
    c : ko.computed(function(){ return a.b() + 1; })
};
```

lets say i REALLY NEED to define my object like in the second code, is there any way to solve that? i have an idea which involves try/catch and a setTimeout, but its going to be ugly, so i wanted to hear if anyone has another idea.

#### EDIT

turns out i dont need try/catch, only a setTimeout, to delay the evaluation past the runtime. but i would like to hear your comments on that nonetheless.

```
var delayedComputed = function( comp, init ){
    var a = ko.observable( init ); 
    // added the initial value because some functions would like to use
    // string or array methods, and would fail to do so on an "undefined"
    setTimout(function (){ 
        var b = ko.computed( comp );
        b.subscribe(a);
        a(b());
    },1);
    return a;
},
a = {
    b : ko.observable(1),
    c : delayedComputed(function(){ return a.b() + 1; },"")
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with *deferEvaluation* to delay the... well... evaluation of the computed until it is actually accessed:

```
var a = {
   b : ko.observable(1),
   c : ko.computed({read: function(){ return a.b() + 1; }, deferEvaluation: true})
};
```

Comment: thanks, i've never seen the `deferEvaluation` flag before. but this wont work if i'll add another property `c : ko.computed(function(){return c() + 1})`. still good to know that there is such a flag

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with the code above - what are you extracting with *c()*? If you meant *a.c()* it would be a recursive call on itself which is (to my knowledge) not permitted.

Comment: blah, i mean `var a = { b:..,c:..,d: ko.computed(function(){return a.c()+1})}`. sorry

Comment: In this case it works still, but you need to specify the *deferEvaluation* modifier on **each** computed observable that must be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constructors like

```
MyViewModel = function() {
   this.b = ko.observable(1);
   this.c = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.b() + 1;
   }, this);
}
```

And then

```
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: i know how to build a viewmodel, thanks. my question is not related to viewmodels though, but more general.

Comment: Above is a solution to your second not working code example, please let us know what your use case is instead of posting code, and maybe we can help you do a good solution. Using setTimeout is always bad practice if your use case isn't to actually time something

Comment: my 'usecase' is as simple as 'i don't want to write `this` a hundred times' :D

Comment: if there's no way around it, then obviously i will write `this` a hundred times, but so fare my solutions works okay.

Comment: Introducing deferred execution for something like that doesn't sound ideal. Sure, one would like that 'this' was implicit, but thats how JS work and you just have to like the situation